Importing contacts fails with: Queue runner must be configured before execution
I'm getting the error "Queue runner must be configured before execution" when importing a list of contacts. The file is just a single column of 416 emails. I've tried the advice given elsewhere on SE to run "cv upgrade:db" but it just responds (correctly) that the system is already upgraded to 5.71.2, and the error continues. I don't see anything relevant in the logs. This is on WP 6.5. Any advice?

Could this be a site with some redirection around ssl or www vs no www ?
Generally the code is looking for qrid in the url to figure out the Queue ID and then it's looking in the $_SESSION to find what the user kicked off - so maybe something in the user session is being lost. Def a hard one to debug.
It is possible to process the queue in the background - but that requires setting up a server process.
Could it be some interaction with a plugin or extension?

I am not aware of any redirection around ssl or www vs no www. Also, we have had issues with interaction with another plugin in the past, but I think that is resolved finally. Can you point me to a doc about setting up a server process to handle the queue in the background? Thanks.

So to run queues in the background there is a utility called 'coworker' that you can install https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/coworker  - to push import jobs to the queue you need to enable a setting too
We have been using this for large jobs (e.g 500k rows that import over a period of days)

"to push import jobs to the queue you need to enable a setting too" - What & where is this setting? I don't see it in the docs.

The setting is under Administer->System Settings->Misc  "Background Queues" - but that is probably a tangent on your issue - my guess is you probably have a malformed record in the civicrm_queue table that is causing issues although we have never quite managed to get to the bottom of reports of this sort of problem - they seem to always kinda disappear when we try to dig in

Well, that worked! I'm kinda surprised given your last comment. All the rows in the civicrm_queue table have status=completed, and the data did in fact get imported. I'd still like to get to the bottom of why it won't import directly, but this'll due for now. Thanks.
